# Recursion-Python coins combination list

Tags: python, list, recursion, combinations

I'm currently trying to write some code which, given a list of coin values, will return all the possible combination of coins summing up to some value. Here's an example of how the program should run:

```
>>> find_changes(4,[1,2,3])
[[1, 1, 1, 1], [2, 1, 1], [1, 2, 1], [3, 1], [1, 1, 2], [2, 2], [1, 3]]
```

I was given the following code template to fill out:

```
def find_changes(n, coins):
    if n < 0:
        return []
    if n == 0:
         return [[]]
    all_changes = []

    for last_used_coin in coins:
        ### DELETE THE "pass" LINE AND WRITE YOUR CODE HERE
        pass

    return all_changes
```

I tried using the following code inside the `for` loop:

```
all_changes.append[last_used_coin]
find_changes(n-last_used_coin,coins)
```

It's currently not working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is it supposed to do? What's going wrong? Homework requires more effort...

Comment: Yes I know , It is supposed to return a list of list of all possible combinations giving us the sum n , I am new to recursion on Python ,so .....

Comment: You should first figure out what your base case is, and then figure out how to break down the problem into smaller sub-problems. If this is hard (because this isn't the easiest recursion question), try to solve something like a Fibonacci recursion first.

Comment: @user2928714 -- Welcome to StackOverflow! The reason you were being downvoted was that on first glance, it looked like you were asking a question without stating what the problem was, or what you were trying to do. I tried fixing some of the problems in your post for you, but in the future, try asking your question more clearly, and learn [how to format](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) your posts on StackOverflow.

Comment: I've succeeded in Fibonacci series ,but not in this question,...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your answer was close, but was failing due to a combination of syntax errors, and logic errors.

Remember, `append` is a method call -- you want add a set of parenthesis around your brackets, like so:

```
all_changes.append([last_used_coin])   
# Add a list of one element to the `all_changes` list
```

However, your code still doesn't quite work. Let's try picking through the code.

If we look at your `for` loop, it's looping through every possible coin in your list. You took the correct next step -- you found all the possible coin combinations for `n - last_used_coin` through your line `find_changes(n - last_used_coin, coins)`.

Now, all you need to do is iterate through all the possible coin combos from calling `find_changes`, add back on `last_used_coin`, and append everything to the `all_changes` list.

Here's the final, working code:

```
def find_changes(n, coins):
    if n < 0:
        return []
    if n == 0:
         return [[]]
    all_changes = []

    for last_used_coin in coins:
        combos = find_changes(n - last_used_coin, coins)
        for combo in combos:
            combo.append(last_used_coin)
            all_changes.append(combo)

    return all_changes

print find_changes(4, [1,2,3])
```

Comment: Thank you very very much Michael ,I highly appreciate it!

Comment: It takes time to adapt the recursive thinking although i fully understand how to apply it on mathematical recursive defintions

Comment: There is a problem ,the output is :[[[[[[1], 1], 1], [[2], 1], 1, 1], [[[[1], 1], 1], [[2], 1], 1, 1], [[[1], 2], 1], [[3], 1]], [[[[[1], 1], 1], [[2], 1], 1, 1], [[[[1], 1], 1], [[2], 1], 1, 1], [[[1], 2], 1], [[3], 1]], [[[[[1], 1], 1], [[2], 1], 1, 1], [[[[1], 1], 1], [[2], 1], 1, 1], [[[1], 2], 1], [[3], 1]], [[[[[1], 1], 1], [[2], 1], 1, 1], [[[[1], 1], 1], [[2], 1], 1, 1], [[[1], 2], 1], [[3], 1]], [[[[1], 1], 2], [[2], 2]], [[[[1], 1], 2], [[2], 2]], [[[1], 3]]]

Comment: @user2928714 -- whoops! It should be fixed now (I was appending `combos` instead of `combo` to `all_changes`)

Comment: Thank you again ,Is there a recommended book for learning recursion ,and recursive thinking (how it works generally .adapting the recursive thinking )-is there also a recommended book -both books should be general of course -not specifically on python...Thanks

Comment: @user2928714 - Here's a [chapter](http://openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english3e/recursion.html) from a Python book that might be useful. You can also check out this [post](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/57243/resources-for-improving-your-comprehension-of-recursion) from Programmers.SE. I can't really think off the top of my head any books that focus specifically on recursion, but every algorithms book in existence is going to focus pretty extensively on recursion, so you could try that.

Comment: Is there any recommended algorithms book?

Comment: @Michael0x2a-Is there any recommended general algorithms book?

Comment: @Michael0x2a for this as input  it is getting into infinite loop.print(find_changes(4, [1,0.5,0.2,0.1,0.05]))